# What is the benefit of SharePoint Hosted Apps compared to the old compoenent like web parts\web forms?

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-hosted-app

What is the benefit of SharePoint Hosted Apps compared to the old components like web parts\web forms?

when is the best time to choose one over the other?

if you need to create a custom content type or a custom action, can you add that to a Hosted Apps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a nutshell, Apps use client-side API, and traditional solutions use server-side API. Apps are more limited in terms what you can do, but are generally considered to be easier to maintain and deploy in the long run when these apps need to span over several SharePoint versions.

[This](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/uksharepoint/2013/03/25/sharepoint-2013-development-apps-versus-solutions/) blog post describes all aspects and links to further articles with details on differences between the two.

Comment: so, for things like web parts, still need to use the old approach. apps will do for a web page but features like web parts and content types still need to be developed the old way on a sp vm

Comment: I'm nowadays more and more deploying e.g., Content Types using PowerShell scripts. Easier to handle update scenarios and in most cases can use CSOM from PowerShell to even deploy stuff remotely without access to console.